# Drawing guitar chords dynamically

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, svg, drawing

So my goal is to draw guitar chords like this using a json file, the number of chords I should create is 924 so there's no way I can do it mannually. [image]

What I have is an array of numbers comma separated (look into position) I am definitely not using fingerings (that's the finger you should use, basically it's a number on top of the circles)

```
[
  {
    "id": "404",
    "name": "Cb",
    "intervals": "",
    "positions": [
      {
        "id": "1226",
        "position": "x,2,4,4,4,2",
        "fingerings": "13331;12341",
        "picture": "",
        "chord_id": "404",
        "instrument_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": "1231",
        "position": "7,9,9,8,7,7",
        "fingerings": "134211",
        "picture": "",
        "chord_id": "404",
        "instrument_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": "1251",
        "position": "7,6,4,4,4,7",
        "fingerings": "321114",
        "picture": "",
        "chord_id": "404",
        "instrument_id": "1"
      },

      ...
```

This is challenging because each chords have several position and some of them are on fret 5 or more so I should indicate which fret we're drawing rather than draw a whole guitar every time.

Second issue is I don't know where exactly I should start and how to handle that correctly, I would love to implement everything in React or Python and then generate a bunch of imgs and use them in my app, this is what I'm comfortable with. I was also thinking about js and css but really how can I write a code that put a circle on that specific place based on a number.

I'm not looking for code, just some links where I can start my research, now I am kinda stuck, please let me know if you need more infos.

Comment: How about starting here: https://www.google.nl/search?q=javascript+guitar+chords+json - finding tools and frameworks are off topic for SO

Comment: My question show up in 6th position, it was posted 5 min ago

Comment: https://github.com/laher/ChordialJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the answer you are expecting for since I don't know anything about guitars and guitar chords. Please take a look.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let json = [
  {
    "id": "404",
    "name": "Cb",
    "intervals": "",
    "positions": [
      {
        "id": "1226",
        "position": "x,2,4,4,4,2",
        "fingerings": "13331;12341",
        "picture": "",
        "chord_id": "404",
        "instrument_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": "1231",
        "position": "7,9,9,8,7,7",
        "fingerings": "134211",
        "picture": "",
        "chord_id": "404",
        "instrument_id": "1"
      },
      {
        "id": "1251",
        "position": "7,6,4,4,4,7",
        "fingerings": "321114",
        "picture": "",
        "chord_id": "404",
        "instrument_id": "1"
      }
      ]
   }
]

for(let j = 0; j < json[0].positions.length; j++){
let position = json[0].positions[j].position.replace("x","").split(",");
let min = Math.min.apply(null, position);
let displacement = min < 1 ? 1 : min;
let svg = drawSVGElement("svg", {viewBox:"0 0 70 60"}, wrap);
drawGrid();

for(let i = 0; i < position.length; i++ ){
if(parseInt(position[i]) > 0){

let cp = {// circle position
  x : 10 + parseInt(i) * 10,
  y : 15 + (position[i] - displacement)*10
}
drawSVGElement("circle",{cx:cp.x,cy:cp.y,r:4}, svg)
}
}




function drawGrid(){
  let d = "";
  for(let i = 1; i < 6; i++){
    d+=`M10,${i*10}H60`
  } 
  for(let i = 1; i < 7; i++){
    d+=`M${i*10},10V50`
  }
  let path = drawSVGElement("path",{"d": d}, svg);
}

function drawSVGElement(tag, o, parent) {
  var svgElement = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, tag);
  for (let name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      svgElement.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(svgElement);
  return svgElement;
}

}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid; max-height:100vh;}
path{fill:none;stroke:red;stroke-linecap: round}
```

```html
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

Comment: hell yeah!! thanks so much, I'll need time to go trough all of this

Answer (score 1):

I would use Python for this, along with Pyx and/or Pillow.

You could start with a basic grid image, knowing the size of each square in your grid would make it quite easy to iterate over and place circles/other markers at specific points and then save the updated version of the image to a new location.

For placing markers, setup constants for width and height respectively, and then multiply by your position variables for each cord (or something to that effect).

JavaScript canvas can also save to image using .toDataUrl() but I've found that Python performed better.